# Selecting all NG-Repeat iterations except the selected one

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-class

Is there a way to do a jQuery like selection of a particular iteration of an ng-repeat?

When editing a particular article I want all the other articles to be faded out so I'm using a function:

```
ng-click="edit(articleKey)"
```

And will be using ng-class to do the specified fading.

How would I go about making the function in the controller have this behaviour?

Comment: Basically I'm looking for a 'not this' option.

Comment: You can use $index to know wich iteration you're in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use $index to do that.

Something like this.

```
  <ion-list>
        <ion-item ng-click="selected.value = $index" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-hide="selected.value === $index">
           Hello, {{item}}!
        </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

Just store the selected value when clicked and instead of ng-hide you can use ng-class to fade out the elements, comparing them to the selected index.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="product in products">                       
        <td ng-class="{'faded_out': !article[product.id].selected, 'faded_in': article[product.id].selected}" ng-click="edit('product.id')">{{ product.id }}</td> 
    </tr>
</tbody>

$scope.products = [{name: "All", articleKey: "212", selected = true},
                    {name: "Termi", articleKey: "4324" selected = true},
                    {name: "911", articleKey: "2323" selected = true}];

$scope.edit = function (articleKey){
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.products.length; i++) {
        if ( $scope.products[i].articleKey === $scope.products[i].articleKey) {
             $scope.products[i].selected = true;
        } else {
            $scope.products[i].selected =false;
        }
    }
}
```